# terraform cloudfront distribution origin - how to update s3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

While creating cloudfront distribution through aws console, we have an option to choose an origin access identity and also, let it update the bucket policy.

I am trying to look for similar options in terraform so that I don't have to manually manage the s3 bucket read permissions for cloudfront origin access identity.

I have checked https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudfront_distribution.html but couldn't find any reference to such option.

Please let me know if I missed checking something on the page.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the responses here and doing some reading and tests on my end, I found that the following achieves the effect we want. Assuming you already have your Cloudfront distribution somewhere:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my-cdn-s3" {
  bucket = "my-cdn"
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "my-oai" {
  comment = "my-oai"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "cdn-cf-policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my-cdn-s3.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.my-cdn-cf-policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "my-cdn-cf-policy" {
  statement {
    sid = "1"
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.my-cdn-oai.iam_arn]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject"
    ]

    resources = [
      "${aws_s3_bucket.my-cdn-s3arn}/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

We would then get this in the bucket's policy, which I have copied from a non-Terraform creation of CF and S3.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-cdn/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Let me know if I left anything out.

Answer (score 2):

Instead you can just create **aws_s3_bucket_policy** like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "cloudfront_s3_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2008-10-17"
    Id      = "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid    = "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
        }
        Action   = "s3:GetObject"
        Resource = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn}/*"
        Condition = {
          StringEquals = {
            "AWS:SourceArn" = aws_cloudfront_distribution.distribution.arn
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

This gives me the same policy proposed by CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you missed anything on that page.  But, you also need to look at this page:
 https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html .
This page covers more detail on setting up S3 buckets.  Note the **policy** line in the  **Static Website Hosting** section.  You can add a line like

```
policy = "${file("policy.json")}"
```

and then you can write whatever policy you need into the **policy.json** file, which then will be included and thereby allow you to avoid needing to manually configure permissions in the console.